How does one get c macro stringification to work with a tick?
I'm working with a C++ project that uses C macro stringification. Currently things are pretty straightforward, but I need to add a string now that contains a single quote '. I'm having trouble getting this to work appropriately. Here is a minimal demonstration of the issue:
#include <stdio.h>

#define myprint(s) \
   printf("passed string: %s", #s)

int main ()
{
    myprint(print this);  // <-- works fine, no quotes.
    printf("\n");
    //myprint(I'm happy); // <-- ' trips things up
    myprint("I'm happy"); // <-- This works, but double 
                          //     quotes are in the output.
    return 0;
}

In godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/oWGxovnPT
What I desire is myprint to make output like this:
I'm happy

Can someone help me to accomplish this?

I provided a minimal example above. In case it's helpful, the exact change I'm trying to make is to add 418 I'm a teapot support to Apache Traffic Server:
https://github.com/apache/trafficserver/blob/2492c84cddce48cb12acd5c799739103e2f648da/src/proxy/hdrs/HTTP.cc#L832-L833

Why do you need this? What is the underlying problem that's supposed to solve? And please note that macros in general is highly discouraged in C++, and that while both C and C++ uses the same preprocessor they are two different languages, and tagging both are also discouraged. Please tag only the language you're actually program in.

Quotes aren't your only problem. Sequences of >1 space will be collapsed to single space, newlines removed, side spaces trimmed.

Why isn't myprint a normal function taking a const char*?

It doesn't work like that: The preprocessor does not consume arbitrary byte soup; rather, it has its own language of things ("tokens") that it understands. And I'm is not one of them. The preprocessor language is loosely aligned with the needs of the "actual" languages that result from preprocessing (C, C++, etc.).

@Someprogrammerdude: added the specific problem I'm working on.

Why can't you simply "-quote the string?

Why use a macro rather than a proper function (and raw string literals)? Macros should generally be avoided.

@HolyBlackCat: stringification will add the literal " quotes to the string.

Are you asking for both myprint(print this); to work (without quotes) and myprint("I'm happy"); to work (without quotes)?

"stringification will add the literal " quotes to the string" If you simply quote every string, you don't need stringification.

The ' begins a character constant, but it is unterminated leading to a syntax error.

Macros work on proper preprocessing tokens, single quote without matching single quote is not a valid preprocessing token. Either you rename it to I am a teapot or you have to give up on the style of this function and add another macro or write the case manually (I honestly don't understand the need for macros here, it's not like it adds any more readability over plain case 100: return "Continue"; chain...)

"stringification will add the literal " quotes" Yes, I'm saying to get rid of stringification and pass quotes manually.

@KerrekSB thank you. It sounds like the "answer" for me is that stringification will not work for this problem space. I'll simply replace each of these with quoted strings. Feel free to add an answer explaining this.

For the Apache code, you could define a similar macro that expects a string argument and doesn't stringify it.

If you want to keep the macros and achieve at least sloppy rfc 2324 compliance, you could choose some similar looking character like the backtick.

Actually this is doable, even if not portably and, frankly, rather ugly. Try myprint(I\x27m happy).

You can't. The solution is to remove the pre-processor stringification.
In your actual use-case, this is just a gratuitous macro. It doesn't even save typing, because HTTP_STATUS_ENTRY is such a long name
What you want is
case 418: return "I'm a teapot";

But while you are there, substitute all the other cases.

Thanks: https://github.com/apache/trafficserver/pull/11273

What you are asking for cannot be done: the preprocessor does not process arbitary input characters, as you might be expecting. Rather, it has its own language (e.g. for C++, see [cpp]; C has a similar specification), where the units of processing are "tokens" (look for the preprocessing-token grammar production).
The "tokens" that the preprocessor processes are aligned with the language that it ultimately services. That is, the preprocessor tokens are somewhat aiming for, but distinct from, the "C++-level" tokens given by the token grammar production in [lex.token].
The character sequence I'm is not a valid preprocessing token.
